# Tumblr Theme Development - Loading and Manipulating Post Notes Appearance

Tags: javascript, tumblr, tumblr-themes, tumblr-html

I'm currently working on a Tumblr theme development project and could use some guidance.

I know Tumblr theme development isn't as common nowadays, but I'm stuck and hoping someone can shed some light.

**Issue:**
I've created a script to manipulate the appearance of post notes, *mimicking* the Tumblr dashboard with categories for reblogs, likes, and comments. However, I'm facing problems when attempting to load more notes.

[image: A screenshot of the post notes from the main dashboard]

**Specifics:**

1. I'm unsure how to re-run the script that Tumblr uses when loading more notes.
2. I need to re-assign the newly loaded notes to the script I created.

**Example:**
Notes are coming from this [URL](https://fukuotest.tumblr.com/notes/737590887394263041/ValQ0Ka2H), and when inspecting the "Show more notes" text, there's an inline script to dynamically load the next notes via `onclick`.

```
if(window.tumblrNotesLoaded)if(tumblrNotesLoaded(notes_html)==false)return;var more_notes_link=document.getElementById('more_notes_737590887394263041');var notes=more_notes_link.parentNode;notes.removeChild(more_notes_link);notes.innerHTML+=notes_html;if(window.tumblrNotesInserted)tumblrNotesInserted(notes_html);}};tumblrReq.open('GET','/notes/737590887394263041/ValQ0Ka2H?from_c=1700827272',true);tumblrReq.send();return false;"
```

---

**Current Code:**

HTML:

```html
{block:Posts}
...

{block:PermalinkPage}
 <article class="posts__perma__tumblr" data-notes-url="{PostNotesURL}" id="notes">
     <!-- the notes will be dynamically inserted here -->
     <div class="posts__perma__tumblr"></div>
 </article>
{/block:PermalinkPage}

{/block:Posts}
```

JS (so long...)

```js
 document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
     separateNotesAndShow();
     loadNotesViaAjax();
 });
 
 // Function to load the notes via AJAX
 // the URL comes from {PostNotesURL}
 // e.g https://fukuotest.tumblr.com/notes/737590887394263041/ValQ0Ka2H
 async function loadNotesViaAjax() {
     var nextNotesURL = document
         .querySelector(".posts__perma__tumblr")
         .getAttribute("data-notes-url");

     if (nextNotesURL) {
         try {
             var response = await fetch(nextNotesURL);
             if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) {
                 var notesHtml = await response.text();
                 tumblrNotesLoaded(notesHtml);
             } else {
                 console.error("Error loading more notes");
             }
         } catch (error) {
             console.error("Fetch error:", error);
         }
     }
 }

 // Function to handle the loading of new notes
 function tumblrNotesLoaded(notes_html) {
     const newNotesContainer = document.createElement("div");
     newNotesContainer.className = "posts__notes__temporary";
     newNotesContainer.innerHTML = notes_html;

     // Extract the notes and update the nextNotesURL for potential further loading
     let newNoteElements =
         newNotesContainer.querySelectorAll("ol.notes > li.note");

     // Append the new notes to their respective categories
     const reblogNotes = [];
     const likeNotes = [];
     const replyNotes = [];
     newNoteElements.forEach((noteElement) => {
         if (noteElement.classList.contains("reblog")) {
             reblogNotes.push(noteElement);
         } else if (noteElement.classList.contains("like")) {
             likeNotes.push(noteElement);
         } else if (noteElement.classList.contains("reply")) {
             replyNotes.push(noteElement);
         }
     });

     appendNewNotes("reblog", reblogNotes);
     appendNewNotes("like", likeNotes);
     appendNewNotes("reply", replyNotes);
 }

 function appendNewNotes(category, newNotes) {
     const container = document.querySelector(`.posts__notes__${ category }`);
     newNotes.forEach((note) => {
         container.appendChild(note);
     });
 }

 function separateNotesAndShow() {
     var reblogNotes = [];
     var likeNotes = [];
     var replyNotes = [];

     var noteElements = document.querySelectorAll("ol.notes > li.note");
     var noteContainer = document.querySelector("ol.notes");
     var noteLoads = document.createElement("div");
     noteLoads.className =
         "posts__notes__load flex flex--align-center flex--justify-center";

     var postsPerma = document.querySelector(".posts__perma__tumblr");

     noteElements.forEach(function (noteElement) {
         if (noteElement.classList.contains("reblog")) {
             reblogNotes.push(noteElement);
         } else if (noteElement.classList.contains("like")) {
             likeNotes.push(noteElement);
         } else if (noteElement.classList.contains("reply")) {
             replyNotes.push(noteElement);
         } else if (noteElement.classList.contains("more_notes_link_container")) {
             noteLoads.appendChild(noteElement);
         }
     });

     createTabButtons();

     // Wrap the notes into a single container
     var notesContainer = document.createElement("div");
     notesContainer.className = "posts__notes__container";

     showNotes("reblog", reblogNotes, notesContainer);
     showNotes("like", likeNotes, notesContainer);
     showNotes("reply", replyNotes, notesContainer);

     postsPerma.appendChild(notesContainer);
     postsPerma.appendChild(noteLoads);

     // Show the reblog notes by default, and hide the others
     showCategory("reblog");
 }

 function createTabButtons() {
     var categories = ["reblog", "like", "reply"];
     var tabsContainer = document.createElement("div");

     tabsContainer.className = "posts__notes__button";

     categories.forEach(function (category) {
         var tabButton = document.createElement("button");
         var notesCount = document.querySelectorAll(
             ".posts__notes__" + category + " > li.note"
         ).length;

         var svgPath = getSVGPath(category);

         tabButton.innerHTML =
             ' <svg fill="currentColor" stroke="1" viewBox="0 0 20 18" width="18px" height="18px" class="margin--right-10">' +
             svgPath +
             '</svg> (' +
             notesCount +
             ') ' +
             category;

         tabButton.className =
             "posts__notes__button-tabs | posts__notes__button-" + category;
         tabButton.id = category + "-button";
         tabButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
             return showCategory(category);
         });
         tabsContainer.appendChild(tabButton);
     });

     var postsPerma = document.querySelector(".posts__perma__tumblr");
     postsPerma.appendChild(tabsContainer);

     var reblogButton = document.getElementById("reblog-button");
     reblogButton.classList.add("active");
 }



 function showCategory(category) {
     var allContainers = document.querySelectorAll(
         ".posts__notes__container > div"
     );
     allContainers.forEach(function (container) {
         container.style.display = "none";
     });

     var allButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".posts__notes__button > button");
     allButtons.forEach(function (button) {
         button.classList.remove("active");
     });

     var selectedContainer = document.querySelector(
         ".posts__notes__" + category
     );
     selectedContainer.style.display = "block";

     var selectedButton = document.getElementById(category + "-button");
     selectedButton.classList.add("active");
 }

 function showNotes(category, notes, container) {
     var notesContainer = document.createElement("div");
     notesContainer.className = "posts__notes__" + category;
     notes.forEach(function (note) {
         notesContainer.appendChild(note);
     });
     container.appendChild(notesContainer);
 }

 function getSVGPath(category) {
     switch (category) {
     case "like":
         return 'M14.658 0c-1.625 0-3.21.767-4.463 2.156-.06.064-.127.138-.197.225-.074-.085-.137-.159-.196-.225C8.547.766 6.966 0 5.35 0 4.215 0 3.114.387 2.162 1.117c-2.773 2.13-2.611 5.89-1.017 8.5 2.158 3.535 6.556 7.18 7.416 7.875A2.3 2.3 0 0 0 9.998 18c.519 0 1.028-.18 1.436-.508.859-.695 5.257-4.34 7.416-7.875 1.595-2.616 1.765-6.376-1-8.5C16.895.387 15.792 0 14.657 0h.001zm0 2.124c.645 0 1.298.208 1.916.683 1.903 1.461 1.457 4.099.484 5.695-1.973 3.23-6.16 6.7-6.94 7.331a.191.191 0 0 1-.241 0c-.779-.631-4.966-4.101-6.94-7.332-.972-1.595-1.4-4.233.5-5.694.619-.475 1.27-.683 1.911-.683 1.064 0 2.095.574 2.898 1.461.495.549 1.658 2.082 1.753 2.203.095-.12 1.259-1.654 1.752-2.203.8-.887 1.842-1.461 2.908-1.461h-.001z';

     case "reblog":
         return 'M12.8.2c-.4-.4-.8-.2-.8.4v2H2c-2 0-2 2-2 2v5s0 1 1 1 1-1 1-1v-4c0-1 .5-1 1-1h9v2c0 .6.3.7.8.4L17 3.6 12.8.2zM4.2 17.9c.5.4.8.2.8-.3v-2h10c2 0 2-2 2-2v-5s0-1-1-1-1 1-1 1v4c0 1-.5 1-1 1H5v-2c0-.6-.3-.7-.8-.4L0 14.6l4.2 3.3z';

     case "reply":
         return 'M8.7 0C4.1 0 .4 3.7.4 8.3c0 1.2.2 2.3.7 3.4-.2.6-.4 1.5-.7 2.5L0 15.8c-.2.7.5 1.4 1.2 1.2l1.6-.4 2.4-.7c1.1.5 2.2.7 3.4.7 4.6 0 8.3-3.7 8.3-8.3C17 3.7 13.3 0 8.7 0zM15 8.3c0 3.5-2.8 6.3-6.4 6.3-1.2 0-2.3-.3-3.2-.9l-3.2.9.9-3.2c-.5-.9-.9-2-.9-3.2.1-3.4 3-6.2 6.5-6.2S15 4.8 15 8.3z';

     default:
         return '';
     }
 }
```

**What I've Achieved So Far:**
I've structured the HTML and JS to handle note separation and loading more notes via AJAX. You can find the demo in the provided [test blog](https://fukuotest.tumblr.com/post/737590887394263041).

---

**Reference**

- There is a [reference from Tumblr docs](https://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes#notes):
  Using the `tumblrNotesInserted()` but still don't know how to incorporate this.
- There is a [reference for the blog](https://pouretrebelle.com/post/729813282406514688/tyler-boswell) that achieves this. And I think their approach is cleaner and easy-to-understand, but not sure about the load of more notes thing (no load more buttons).

---

**Request for Help:**

- I'm looking for guidance on re-running the script for loading more notes and re-assigning them correctly. There is a [similar question on 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10138876/running-a-function-when-loading-more-notes-in-tumblr) but still have no idea how to append the new notes.
- An approach to dynamically load more new notes via AJAX.
- And be able to implement the function without an issue.

Comment: Welcome to SO! I suggest that you do not post images as links; instead, just paste where  you want it to show up.

Comment: Thank you @MarceloScofanoDiniz for the warm welcome! Unfortunately, I cannot seem to insert the image since I did not gain enough reputation to do so. It's embedded as a link for now 

Comment: Is the long JS file inside your theme?

Comment: Hello @lharby. Yes! The JS is inside my test blog here: https://fukuotest.tumblr.com/post/737590887394263041#notes

As you can see there, the script has been implemented and is working properly. However, I still don't know how to make the "load more notes" button append the new notes (it's only showing the latest notes without a load more button).

Comment: I am a bit confused, but I started to try and look into this here: https://jsfiddle.net/lharby/ovxngh13/ it seems as though when you call the next block of notes the last one in that block contains the js to call the following block. So if you are trying to recreate that yourself you would need a way to cancel the click behaviour of the last note call function.

Comment: Or is it that you don't have a way to call the notes on the first call? If that is the case it should be relatively easy to create a button/anchor in the markup and pass the notes url to it, then when you click it for the first time, on success you can make that button disappear and then load the next notes block from the url (so the last one will contain the call to the next notes block). Failing that you could use a single static button and on success from the first call pass in the next url of notes and update (rather like using an offset). But I think that is more work.

Comment: In my jsfiddle example I used a DomParser to iterate through the list items, I don't want to keep appending the entire block of html to the dom, because then it will create additional `<ol>`s which will keep incrementing the list count from 1. 
Sorry I realise this is bombarding you a little, but it's still not 100% clear what you are trying to do, and that Tumblr already offers this functionality.

Comment: Hello @lharby! Thank you very much for taking the time to assist me! Yes, as you mentioned, Tumblr already provides functionality for post notes. Currently, I am working on mimicking the post notes functionality similar to what is displayed on the Tumblr dashboard into three categories: reblog, likes, and replies. I was struggling to figure out how to add new notes to the existing ones for my experimentation.

Comment: Thanks to you, I finally figured it out. I didn't know about the `DOMParser()` API, which greatly helped me, I was able to append the new notes to the existing ones using the button.  Here's the updated code if you want to try it out: https://codepen.io/fukuo/pen/wvOBOvg. It might not be perfect and may need additional fixes, but the idea is already implemented there. I will update the answer here later! Thank you again for the help! 

Comment: Whoops, I forgot to include the working demo as well. Here's the working demo to check https://fukuotest.tumblr.com/post/737590887394263041! It should be working without the CORS issue hopefully

Comment: That's excellent. You should answer your own question as you clearly know what you're doing. Also very good code comments on the codepen repo. All looks like it's working to me.